# Error when accessing python from the prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Michael:~ Michael$ python
```

> Could not find platform independent libraries 
>   Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to [:]
>   Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>   ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

I cannot access python from the terminal, please help?

Comment: How did you install Python on your mac?

Comment: i both downloaded pyzon, anaconda from the web and then brew install python from the terminal. It did work in recent times. Could you please help me by either solving the problem or simply uninstalling and reinstalling everything from the beginning?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you downloaded it AND used brew. Do this: `brew uninstall python` then to again `brew install python`. After you do this, make sure you have the line `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` in your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: where is my profile line? Also if i run python3 in the prompt it will let me access it and also if i run python2. But when I run which python the following comes up .. MacBook-Pro-di-Michael:~ Michael$ which python
/Users/Michael/anaconda/bin/python

Comment: So you're saying it works now? No need to worry about the `~/.profile` if your problem is solved...

Comment: ok, thank you anyways